# JavaScript browser agent redirect

Tags: javascript, iphone, browser, agent

I've got this little bit of code on my webpage header to redirect the user to a different page if they are using an iPhone:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) ||  
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) {  
document.location = "iPhone.aspx"; }
</script>
```

Is there an easy way to 'reverse' this code, so anyone landing on the iPhone page from ANY other browser will be redirected back to the home page?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution. Replace your existing one with this.

```
if(!/(iphone|ipod)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   window.location = "Desktop.aspx";
}
```

Updated since its only for iPhone page.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse? Replace `!= -1` with `== -1`

Edit:

Suppose you mean something like this:

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) ||  
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) {  
document.location = "iPhone.aspx"; } else {
document.location = "notiPhone.aspx";
}
```

Comment: I tried:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') == -1) ||
    (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') == -1)) {
    document.location = "Default.aspx";}
    </script>

However, it just sends the iPhone on a loop, bouncing from Default.aspx to iPhone.aspx

Comment: You should log or alert the userAgent string and have a look to see if your string matches. Also, try alert(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone')) - what comes up?

Answer (score 0):

`(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') == -1` means there is no such string "iPhone" in the userAgent. So when you change from `!=` to `==`, you need to change `||` to `&&` as well.

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') == -1) 
   && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') == -1)) {  
    document.location = 'default.aspx';
}
```